# Spring Integration: tail-inbound-channel-adapter: (1)How can I pass dynamic file name and (2)Programmatically trigger the poller

Tags: spring-integration

I have a requirement to tail a file so I am using **tail-inbound-channel-adapter**.

There are couple of challenges.
File name and the file path changes for every batch run. I was looking for some regex support like this attribute (filename-regex) found in inbound-channel-adapter. I only see an attribute called file in tail-inbound-channel-adapter which expects a static file name (as shown below). How do I pass in the dynamic file name to tail-inbound-channel-adapter.

```
<int-file:tail-inbound-channel-adapter channel="fileChannel" file="xyz" delay="999999999999999" end="false" reopen="true" file-delay="999999999999999" />
```

The other challange is that I dont want this poller to start polling right away when the application comes up. Instead it should start polling when the file is ready for tailing. How do I control that?

As shown above, I tried assigning some big delay in the config file and then tried to modify the delay value during the runtime. But that did not help.

Any other alternative ways for my requirements. Thanks for your valuable input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adapter implements `SmartLifecycle`.

Set `auto-startup="false"`. Get a reference to the adapter (e.g. `@AutoWired` or `context.getBean("foo",  FileTailingMessageProducerSupport.class)`), assuming the adapter has `id="foo"`.

To start the adapter use `foo.start()`.

To change the file, `foo.stop(); foo.setFile(newFile); foo.start();`.

Comment: Thanks Gary. You nailed it man. Its working as explained. I appricate your help and prompt reply.

Comment: Gary, A related questions on this topic. Currently I am able to set the file on the fly, start and stop the file tailing dynamically through FileTailingMessageProducerSupport. Now when another job is triggered by the user, a new file is getting created which needs to polled and tailed in the same way. Because FileTailingMessageProducerSupport is creatd by the <int-file:tail-inbound-channel-adapter ...> configuration and a singleton class, when the second job sets the new file name the tailing for the first job no longer happens. Any idea to overcome this use case would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Gary, Please note that our jobs are long running jobs. So it is very much possible to have two or three jobs running at the sametime, which means they all must be able to poll/tail their own file simultaniously. I was thinking if I can create FileTailingMessageProducerSupport class myself I can create them per run. But this class is an abstract class. I could not find which class implements this one. Is there any better thoughts?

Comment: Yes, you will have to instantiate an adapter for each one. The two implementations (subclasses) of `FileTailingMessageProducerSupport ` are `OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer` and `ApacheCommonsFileTailingMessageProducer`. The `FileTailInboundChannelAdapterFactoryBean` decides which one to create, based on the attributes. I generally recommend using the OS delegating adapter when running on operating systems that have a `tail` command.

Comment: Gary, Thanks for the hint. Now for each job, I am able to instantiate ApacheCommonsFileTailingMessageProducer class on Windows and  OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer on Linux. When I run the job on Linux I am getting **IOException: Cannot run program "ADAPTER_NOT_INITIALIZED": error=2, No such file or directory** Please note that I am setting file, TailAttemptsDelay and **-F -n +0** as Options for OSDelegatingFileTailingMessageProducer and starting the same. The file that gets polled is created by a Python script which takes a few mins to start writing the file...

Comment: ... wondering what would be the right option to set so that the process would not fail until the file is found and then start consuming. I thought -F would do the --retry. For us the file should be always read from the beginning so that incase if the process exits abnormally, the file would get consumed from the beginning and then tail for new lines when the job is restarted.

Comment: If you are creating the adapter outside of a Spring application context, you need to invoke `afterPropertiesSet()`. For more debugging, I suggest you turn on debug logging to see what's going on; you need `-n 99999` or similar to tail from the beginning,

Comment: That's `-n +0` (more efficient)